Calculate total price with Laravel
I have flights carrying parcels and need to display the expected cost depending on the weight of all the parcels.
The price per 1kg = 28.88, so if the total weight of the parcels is 5.2kg the total is:
5.2 * 28.88 = 150.176
I also have a single price for each parcel.
This is my code
class FlightTotal
{
    public static function payable($parcels)
    {
        $unpaidParcels = $parcels->where('is_paid', 0);

        $payable = [...$unpaidParcels->map(function ($unpaidParcel) {
            return PriceCalculator::calculatePrice(
                $unpaidParcel->volume_weight && $unpaidParcel->volume_weight != '0.00'
                    ? $unpaidParcel->volume_weight
                    : $unpaidParcel->physical_weight,
                $unpaidParcel->flight?->remoteAddress->id,
                $unpaidParcel->user->id,
                $unpaidParcel->user->type
            );
        })];

        return array_sum($payable);
    }

    public static function amount($parcels)
    {
        $paidParcels = $parcels->where('is_paid', 1);

        $totalPaidAmount = 0;

        foreach ($paidParcels as $paidParcel) {
            $totalPaidAmount += abs($paidParcel->price);
        }

        return self::payable($parcels) + $totalPaidAmount;

    }
}

class PriceCalculator
{
    public static function custom_number_format($price, $weight)
    {
        $formatted = number_format($price * $weight, 2, '.', '');

        if ($formatted > 1000 && substr($formatted, -3) == '.00') {
            $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -3);
        }

        return $formatted;
    }

    public static function calculatePrice($weight, $remoteAddressId, $userId, $organisation)
    {
        $organisation = $organisation == 'individual' ? 0 : 1;

        $personalPrice = PersonalPrice::where('remote_address_id', $remoteAddressId)
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->first();

        $priceRange = PriceRange::where('remote_address_id', $remoteAddressId)
            ->where('from', '<=', $weight)
            ->where('to', '>=', $weight)
            ->where('organisation', $organisation)
            ->first();

        $remoteAddress = RemoteAddress::findOrFail($remoteAddressId);

        if ($personalPrice) {
            return number_format($personalPrice->price * $weight, 2);
        }

        if ($priceRange) {
            return number_format($priceRange->price * $weight, 2);
        }

        if ($organisation == 0) {
            return self::custom_number_format($remoteAddress->rest_price, $weight);
        } else {
            return self::custom_number_format($remoteAddress->organisation_rest_price, $weight);
        }
    }
}

When I have a total parcel weight of 9.6 it calculated the charge as 277.27 instead of 277.248 rounded to 277.25.
In another case the total weight is 249.09 and the result was calculated as 7193.88 instead of 7193.7192 (rounded to 7193.72)
The ChatGPT recommends that I use BCMath or GMP Libraries but it return same results.

I can't reproduce your error. The PHP number_format function rounds "half up" so your result of 277.248 is rounded to 277.25 when $price = 28.88 and $weight = 9.6. Unless you can show how the 277.27 result is returned I can't help you. Your code has multiple paths of execution, which is it using? Simplify your example code until you have a minimal, reproducible example.

After editing your question I noticed you said "I also have a single price for each parcel".  Are you sure you are using the 28.88 price in your calculations and not a $personalPrice or $priceRange?

perhaps your result got rounded half-up a few times, leading to 277.27. Try setting the second parameter of number_format to 3
